# MYSQL Query INNER JOIN Show Result

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Query as below

```
SELECT b1.vin, f1.reg, COUNT(*), b1.reg
FROM beame AS b1
INNER JOIN fleet AS f1
ON b1.vin = f1.vin
WHERE f1.vin IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b1.vin
```

I have two Tables with exact details in them. The group functions shows me duplicates as this is important for me to see. BEAME has 1000 entries and FLEET has 900 entries. I need to echo the 100 entries that is not in FLEET from BEAME VIN is the common join between the two tables.

I need to see the result of the VIN numbers that is not in FLEET Table but is in BEAME Table

Grouping the SQL COUNTING the duplictaes

Comment: Why return two columns named `reg` - you will not be able to identify which is which?

Comment: Would `WHERE f.vin IS NOT NULL and b.vin NOT IN ( SELECT vin FROM fleet )` not work as the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join(as BEAME is on the left side , left join returns only values on the left side but assumes null values on the right side which are absent)
instead of inner join and
filter by using where or group by& having fleet not null